# fail2ban jail is not respected

Tags: apache2, fail2ban

I'm completely new to fail2ban.  I implemented a custom filter and a custom jail to ban some users from accessing my website which is hosted by apache.  Fail2ban seems to recognize my regex fail rules and I do see IP addresses I expect to go to jail are actually going into the jail.  But jailed users are still able to access my website and I don't see any iptables rules that indicate it is aware of the presence of fail2ban.  How can I use fail2ban to prevent users from accessing my website.

So here are the files that I have:

`/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-custom.conf`

```
[Definition]

badagents =

failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST|HEAD) \/+dns-query.*$

ignoreregex =
```

`/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`

```
[INCLUDES]
before = paths-debian.conf

[DEFAULT]
ignorecommand =
bantime  = 10m
findtime  = 10m
maxretry = 5
maxmatches = %(maxretry)s
backend = auto
usedns = warn
logencoding = auto
enabled = false
mode = normal
filter = %(__name__)s[mode=%(mode)s]
destemail = root@localhost
sender = root@localhost
mta = sendmail
protocol = tcp
chain = <known/chain>
port = 0:65535
fail2ban_agent = Fail2Ban/%(fail2ban_version)s
banaction = iptables-multiport
banaction_allports = iptables-allports
action_ = %(banaction)s[port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
action_mw = %(action_)s
            %(mta)s-whois[sender="%(sender)s", dest="%(destemail)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]

action_mwl = %(action_)s
             %(mta)s-whois-lines[sender="%(sender)s", dest="%(destemail)s", logpath="%(logpath)s", chain="%(chain)s"]

action_xarf = %(action_)s
             xarf-login-attack[service=%(__name__)s, sender="%(sender)s", logpath="%(logpath)s", port="%(port)s"]

action_cf_mwl = cloudflare[cfuser="%(cfemail)s", cftoken="%(cfapikey)s"]
                %(mta)s-whois-lines[sender="%(sender)s", dest="%(destemail)s", logpath="%(logpath)s", chain="%(chain)s"]

action_blocklist_de  = blocklist_de[email="%(sender)s", service="%(__name__)s", apikey="%(blocklist_de_apikey)s", agent="%(fail2ban_agent)s"]

action_badips = badips.py[category="%(__name__)s", banaction="%(banaction)s", agent="%(fail2ban_agent)s"]

action_badips_report = badips[category="%(__name__)s", agent="%(fail2ban_agent)s"]

action_abuseipdb = abuseipdb

action = %(action_)s


[apache-custom]
enabled  = true
logpath  = /var/log/apache2/access.log
action   = iptables-ipset-proto6[name=apache-custom, port="http,https", protocol=tcp, bantime=-1]
findtime = 86400
bantime  = -1
maxretry = 1
```

When I run the command `fail2ban-client status apache-custom`, I see the following details:

```
Status for the jail: apache-custom
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 0
|  |- Total failed:     25
|  `- File list:        /var/log/apache2/access.log
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 4
   |- Total banned:     4
   `- Banned IP list:   49.12.196.18 38.132.118.73 216.244.66.231 38.112.49.40
```

The IP `38.112.49.40` is my cousin's phone, and he can still see my website despite fail2ban saying he's been jailed.

I do not see any mention of any of the 4 ip addresses in my `iptables -L -n`.

What am I doing wrong?  How do I ban these 4 ip addresses from being able to see my website over `http` and `https`?

---

SOLUTION:

OK, I can get around the problem by removing the line

```
action   = iptables-ipset-proto6[name=apache-custom, port="http,https", protocol=tcp, bantime=-1]
```

I think without that line, then fail2ban will use the default action. I am not entirely sure, because I am still learning how all this works.  Will continuing reading tutorials/blogs/documentations I see online to learn how fail2ban really works.